# Using the genres filter on Soundcloud API

Tags: soundcloud

I am using the genres filter on Soundcloud API, the codes:

```
$tracks = $client->get('tracks', array('genres' => 'punk'));
```

It is working well and return all tracks which genre are punk, but when I try to change the codes:

```
$tracks = $client->get('tracks', array('genres' => 'rock'));
```

It can not return  all tracks which genre are rock.

My question is: where can we find correct music genres from Soundcloud?

Maybe the Soundcloud API which should give us a method to get a list for common genres.

Comment: it is always useful to let people know what language / technology you are using.

Comment: It is about the Soundcloud API and any languages/technology will have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, we do not offer a way of retrieving list of genres. You can look into discussions [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=get%20all%20genres%20soundcloud%20api&oq=get%20all%20genres%20soundcloud%20api&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=site%3agroups.google.com%20get%20all%20genres%20soundcloud%20api&oq=site%3agroups.google.com%20get%20all%20genres%20soundcloud%20api&gs_l=serp.3...4339.11035.0.11397.31.27.4.0.0.19.302.5517.0j13j13j1.27.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.22juihcs3XA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=f3be7966d981f367&bpcl=37643589&biw=1440&bih=733).

Please test this link, it seems to work for me: http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?genres=rock&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID

If the problem is with particular SDK, please let us now so we could look into it.

Comment: what happened to browse tracks by genre? it returns 503 error.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735941/genres-and-types-filters-not-working-in-soundcloud-api/17808120