# Genres and types filters not working in Soundcloud API?

Tags: python, python-2.7, soundcloud

This [link](http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?genres=rock&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID)
does not return tracks from the rock genre as described in this post: [Using the genres filter on Soundcloud API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285555/using-the-genres-filter-on-soundcloud-api)

Is this something that recently broke?

I'm using the Python SDK and have tried various calls to get the filter to work, and currently I can only get the created_at filter to be respected. Here is the python code:

```
track_page=client.get('/tracks', 
            created_at={'from':'2013-01-01 00:00:00','to':'2013-01-07 00:00:00'}, 
            genre='house',
            types=['recording','remix','original'],
            limit=limit_size,
            offset=offset)
```

The relevant documentation is [here](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks)

Comment: yes, its not working at the moment in my apps too. `tags` filter is also broken.

Comment: created_at doesn't seem to be working now either...everyone please tweet @soundcloud to get them to address this issue!

Comment: `created_at` stopped working 1-2 month ago and it was announced by soundcloud. this is some bug on soundcloud servers. i already twitted about `genres` and `tags`. no response from @scsupport

Comment: just noticed that `duration[from]` and `duration[to]` are not working either. soundcloud really messed up something with theirs last maintenance.

Comment: anyone know if it's possible to filter for more than one genre at a time? genres={'House','Techno'} returns a 503 error every time.

Comment: it returns 503 even for 1 genre at a time :( soundcloud messed up something again.

Comment: Almost november and filter still does not work.

Comment: Yup, I periodically check every couple of weeks and nada

Answer (score 1):

i just found a solution, add `q='*'` in your query. it will return correct results for the genre.

but i'm not sure about `created_at[from/to]` and `duration[from/to]`

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure out the created[from/to] piece?

Comment: is duration a deprecated feature now? it's still not working for me

Answer (score 0):

They haven't blogged about this change, but given that they're responding with `400 Client Error` and the message "'q' parameter is required", it looks like you MUST supply a query now. (This is a new error that wasn't there a few days ago AFAIK).

I just tried passing an empty `q` parameter with a genre filter and it seemed to return appropriately filtered results.

Comment: nope, its not that. api call without q params is returning the results. problem is that change in genres param will not change the results.

Comment: Super weird — this morning they required the `q` parameter, but as of now my requests work fine without it, including the `genre` param.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code shows that you're passing a `genre` parameter instead of the plural `genres` parameter. Make sure your actual code uses the plural — Soundcloud's API silently ignores the singular, as I learned the hard way last week.

Comment: Good catch, but I have tried it both ways. Just pasted in the wrong code in the OP.

Comment: Huh. Well, the link you posted at the top of your question works for me (even if I change the `genre` param). See my other example for evidence that their API doesn't seem super… stable.

Comment: genres is now working, but the other filters still don't seem to be.

Comment: genres and tags are down again